# SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I am using Sharepoint Foundation 2010. I got `error message(824)` in Event logs while executing regular schedule job for backing up databases.

WSS_Logging  is showing error below:

> "SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0xa691e24a; actual: 0xb68ce671). It occurred during a read of page (1:6095) in database ID 9 at offset 0x00000002f9e000 in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\WSS_Logging.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). "

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

**[From MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337274.aspx)**

**What does this error mean:**
This error indicates that Windows reports that the page is successfully read from disk, but SQL Server has discovered something wrong with the page. This error is similar to error 823 except that Windows did not detect the error. This usually indicates a problem in the I/O subsystem, such as a failing disk drive, disk firmware problems, faulty device driver, and so on

simply put[,run CHKDSK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872425.aspx) and see if you get any errors

```
CHKDSK [volume[[path]filename]] [/F] [/V] [/R] [/X] [/I] [/C] [/L[:size]]
```

and also change the [page_verify option to checksum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb402873.aspx) if you haven't

Read below for more details from MSDN link

**what are next steps:**

***Look for Hardware Failure***

Run hardware diagnostics and correct any problems. Also examine the Microsoft Windows system and application logs and the SQL Server error log to see whether the error occurred because of hardware failure. Fix any hardware-related problems that are contained in the logs.
If you have persistent data corruption problems, try to swap out different hardware components to isolate the problem. Check to make sure that the system does not have write-caching enabled on the disk controller. If you suspect write-caching to be the problem, contact your hardware vendor.
Finally, you might find it useful to switch to a new hardware system. This switch may include reformatting the disk drives and reinstalling the operating system.

***Restore from Backup***

If the problem is not hardware-related and a known clean backup is available, restore the database from the backup.
Consider changing the databases to use the PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM option.

Comment: Hi Gamesiwar,
Thanks for your feeback.....
I was also not able  to create backup of that database it is showing  error " inconsistent-metadata"

Also Checked the CHKDSK command there is  not bad sectors in it.

Answer (score -1):

DBCC CHECKDB (yourdatabasename)

and DBCheck will give errors against the tables.
You can do repair each table with this function CHECKTABLE('tablename1', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
USE yourdatabasename;
GO

ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename
SET single_user;
GO

DBCC CHECKTABLE('tablename1', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
GO

DBCC CHECKTABLE('tablename2', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
GO

ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename
SET MULTI_USER;
GO

USE dbreckitInventory;
GO

ALTER DATABASE dbreckitInventory
SET single_user;
GO

DBCC CHECKTABLE('tblpurchasedetails', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
GO

DBCC CHECKTABLE('TblSalesDetails', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
GO

ALTER DATABASE dbreckitInventory
SET MULTI_USER;
GO